# Render an Array returns the correct amount but not displaying information in it

Tags: reactjs

This is my data:

[image]

This is how I get my data and display a Card:

```
// Mainpage Links and Categories //
const MainpageLinks = () => {

    const [mainpageDataCategories, setDataCategories] = useState([]);

    React.useEffect( () => {

        const getMainpageData = async () => {
            let responseMainpage = await axios.get("ajax/api/mainpage_links")
            const responseMainpageData = responseMainpage.data;

            // Get the unique categories
            const arrMainpageData = responseMainpageData.map(m => m.category);
            const setMainpageData = new Set(arrMainpageData);
            const uniqueCategories = Array.from(setMainpageData);
            setDataCategories(uniqueCategories)

            console.log(uniqueCategories);

        }

        getMainpageData();}, []);

    return (

        <>
            {mainpageDataCategories.map(({ mainpageDataCategories }) => (

            <Cards.Item
                overline={mainpageDataCategories}
                headline={mainpageDataCategories}
                thumbIcon={communication___call}
                subline={mainpageDataCategories}
                thumbTitle="Test"
                centeredLayout
                actions={
                    <IconLink
                        icon={communication___call}
                        href="#"
                        look={IconLink.Looks.RIGHT}
                        onClick={() => console.log("IconLink clicked!")}
                    >
                        Mehr erfahren
                    </IconLink>
                }
            />

            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

The result shows the correct amount of `<Card>` items, but the data is not displayed. The same piece of code works if my data has values like `[{"team": "1", "name": "tom"}]`.

How can I correctly display the values in my array in my `<Card>` item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here how you make your map `mainpageDataCategories.map(({ mainpageDataCategories }) =>` says map this array to another array. But in the function you tell it to use the field  `{ mainpageDataCategories }`from the object in the array. This does not even exist and it uses the same name as the state which will confuse it even more.
Try to do this instead:

```js
mainpageDataCategories.map(( category ) => (

            <Cards.Item
                overline={category}
                headline={category}
                thumbIcon={communication___call}
                subline={category}
                thumbTitle="Test"
                centeredLayout
                actions={
                    <IconLink
                        icon={communication___call}
                        href="#"
                        look={IconLink.Looks.RIGHT}
                        onClick={() => console.log("IconLink clicked!")}
                    >
                        Mehr erfahren
                    </IconLink>
                }
            />

            ))
```

You could considering moving over to typescript or get a linter to help you catch this problems while coding.

Comment: Hi Disco, thank you for your response. I also tried to name the field "category" or "data" but it pretty much does not matter if I name it "category" or "blabla" - I still do not get the values shown

Comment: could you post and example of when you did that. Its important that you do not use curly brackets `{}` since that will try to decompose the object. And this is just an array for strings

Comment: Oh god. Im sorry. thank you for the hint with the curly brackets. you are correct. thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
{mainpageDataCategories.map((item) => (

        <Cards.Item
            overline={item}
            headline={item}
            thumbIcon={communication___call}
            subline={item}
            thumbTitle="Test"
            centeredLayout
            actions={
                <IconLink
                    icon={communication___call}
                    href="#"
                    look={IconLink.Looks.RIGHT}
                    onClick={() => console.log("IconLink clicked!")}
                >
                    Mehr erfahren
                </IconLink>
            }
        />

        ))}
```

This syntax seems incorrect, try this instead.
If still not working, try to log what item (in your case mainpageDataCategories), and be sure that Cards.Item component render the text in that way.